# 0xabababab/0xbadf00d error after calling for "new" on a class 2 times in a row

Tags: c++, memory, constructor

I have been breaking my head on this for a while now and can't find the issue. 
Basically I want to create a class A that create 2 other classes of type B:
EDIT: added this code snippet. This gave sys2b 0xbaadf00d address.

```
class SystemA
{
private:
   int *root;
   int size;
public:
   SystemA() : root(nullptr), size(0){}
};
class SystemB
{
private:
   int *root;
   int type;
public:
   SystemB(int os) : root(nullptr), type(os){}
};
class Box
{
private:
   SystemA* sys1;
   SystemB* sys2a;
   SystemB* sys2b;
public:
Box()
{
    sys1 = new SystemA();
    sys2a = new SystemB(1);
    sys2b = new SystemB(0);
}
~Box()
{
    delete sys1;
    delete sys2a;
    delete sys2b;
}
};
int main(){
   Box* pBox = new Box();
   delete pBox;
   return 0;
}
```

(there is no inheritance here by the way). Compiled with:

g++ -g -Wall -std=c++11 -DNDEBUG .\test.cpp -o test.exe
[image: VS code Debugger]

Basically SystemA and SystemB both are binary search trees where I want to initialize the root (in both) to be NULLs. I have other functions to insert nodes into it which they in turn will create the nodes.

Problem is that after the construction of this Box when I look at the address of sys2b (in debug mode) I get `0xabababab` or 0xbaadf00d address while the sys1 and sys2b are pointing to NULL.

from my investigation here [Memory Bit Patterns](https://www.softwareverify.com/memory-bit-patterns.php) I am trying to access memory no within my allocated memory but how can that be? Why sys2a points to NULL as I want while sys2b gets 0xabababab or 0xbaadf00d?

Expected:

After calling new on Box, I expect the pointers sys1, sys2a, sys2b to point to a their relevant classes while also have their root fields be NULLs

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this member initializer list `: SystemA(NULL), SystemB(NULL), SystemB(NULL)`? `ManagerSystem` does not inherit from any of these classes accodring to your example.

Comment: seems you have a typo in your question... what is the final condition? sys1 has value, sys2a is NULL and sys2b is 0xababababab?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I have added some more explenation. I do think that the initializer list there is irrelevant as you suggest.

Comment: Please add real code, the constructor definition you have wouldn't compile

Comment: The [mcve] is essential here. It would seem likely to me that either your `ManagerSystem` is being freed or stomped over. But we cannot be sure or point out where you've gone wrong without the mcve.

Comment: Hey all, I have edited the post with much detail and code for you to compile and see for yourself. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Mat i have edited a code for you to compile which has compiled for me and got the same issue.

Comment: @GeorgesupportsGoFundMonica I think that you will be able to compile the code I have added now.

Comment: The program doesn't produce any output, nor it is expected to. I don't see any problem with it. If you have a program that produces unexpected output, post it. Otherwise there is no question. Scteenshots of your debugger are not very meaningful unless your program doesn't produce unexpected output on its own.

Comment: Your edit is extremely important. Can you double check that the described problem still occurs with the edited code? Please update the results you show.

Comment: I think the problem here is that my code on the project is much bigger and maybe the issue is somewhere else. I mean I still get 0xbaadf00d there. Should I post a github link or just paste it all here? thx

Comment: The problem is, we generally cannot troubleshoot code we cannot see. The question should be slef contained so please no github links.Too much code is a guarantee of no one willing to look at it, so pasting it all here is problematic too. You should create a [mcve] by throwing away irrelevant parts of your code, making sure the problem is still there after each round of cleanup. In the end, just the problematic part remains.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I will try to add something that can be reproduced as I can see it as well.

Comment: _I think the problem here is that my code on the project is much bigger and maybe the issue is somewhere else._ How could we help you if the problem is code that you didn't post?

Comment: I'd advise setting aside some time to learn about the vs debug tools. You could set a data breakpoint on each system, it will then break with a callstack whenever a system pointer is set.

Answer (score 1):

Okay after being very confused with it all I found the problem.

The function that called for the constructor and any other functions for the class used pointers but didn't use them correctly so incorrect pointers led to the class' functions to get incorrect data. That's why I got the baadf00d or abababab memory error.

Sorry for the confusion and frustration everyone.